# Does Moshi have a Runtime Type Adapter Factory like Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, moshi

I've been using Gson for a few weeks and I've discovered the Runtime Type Adapter Factory class that allows to "adapt values whose runtime type may differ from their declaration type".

Here's my current code using Gson:

```
public class Database {
private final Gson gson;

private Database() {
    // Initialize Gson
    RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Base> runtimeTypeAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
            .of(Base.class, "table")
            .registerSubtype(AdminsTbl.class, "admins");
    this.gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(runtimeTypeAdapterFactory).create();
}
}
```

I have a "table" field in my JSON that tells Gson which class to use (in this case: "admins" -> AdminsTbl.class). Is there something like this in Moshi?

Comment: https://github.com/square/moshi/pull/264/files is a basic working example. there are some things to be improved, but this will work alright for many use cases.

Comment: @EricCochran Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, Gson does not provide `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` per se in its standard bundle. Quick googling for a Moshi implementation brings your question at the top of the search results, at least for me. :) I also couldn't find anything like that in the [`com.squareup.moshi.recipes`](https://github.com/square/moshi/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/recipes) package. But you can easily implement it yourself:

```java
public final class MoshiRuntimeTypeJsonAdapterFactory
        implements JsonAdapter.Factory {

    private static final String DEFAULT_CLASS_NAME_PROPERTY = "type";

    private final Class<?> baseClass;
    private final String classNameProperty;
    private final Map<String, Class<?>> classNameToClass = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Class<?>, String> classToClassName = new HashMap<>();

    private MoshiRuntimeTypeJsonAdapterFactory(final Class<?> baseClass, final String classNameProperty) {
        this.baseClass = baseClass;
        this.classNameProperty = classNameProperty;
    }

    public static MoshiRuntimeTypeJsonAdapterFactory of(final Class<?> expectedClass) {
        return new MoshiRuntimeTypeJsonAdapterFactory(expectedClass, DEFAULT_CLASS_NAME_PROPERTY);
    }

    public static MoshiRuntimeTypeJsonAdapterFactory of(final Class<?> expectedClass, final String classNameProperty) {
        return new MoshiRuntimeTypeJsonAdapterFactory(expectedClass, classNameProperty);
    }

    public MoshiRuntimeTypeJsonAdapterFactory with(final Class<?> concreteClass) {
        return with(concreteClass, concreteClass.getSimpleName());
    }

    public MoshiRuntimeTypeJsonAdapterFactory with(final Class<?> concreteClass, final String className)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if ( classNameToClass.containsKey(className) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(className + " is already registered for " + concreteClass);
        }
        if ( classToClassName.containsKey(concreteClass) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(concreteClass + " is already registered for " + className);
        }
        classNameToClass.put(className, concreteClass);
        classToClassName.put(concreteClass, className);
        return this;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public JsonAdapter<?> create(final Type type, final Set<? extends Annotation> annotations, final Moshi moshi) {
        if ( !(type instanceof Class) ) {
            return null;
        }
        final Class<?> typeAsClass = (Class<?>) type;
        if ( !baseClass.isAssignableFrom(typeAsClass) ) {
            return null;
        }
        final JsonAdapter<Object> jsonObjectJsonAdapter = moshi.nextAdapter(this, Map.class, ImmutableSet.of());
        final LoadingCache<Class<?>, JsonAdapter<Object>> jsonAdaptersCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .build(new CacheLoader<Class<?>, JsonAdapter<Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public JsonAdapter<Object> load(final Class<?> clazz) {
                        return moshi.nextAdapter(MoshiRuntimeTypeJsonAdapterFactory.this, clazz, ImmutableSet.copyOf(clazz.getAnnotations()));
                    }
                });
        return new JsonAdapter<Object>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Object fromJson(final JsonReader jsonReader)
                    throws IOException {
                try {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    final Map<String, Object> jsonObject = (Map<String, Object>) jsonReader.readJsonValue();
                    assert jsonObject != null;
                    final Object rawClassName = jsonObject.get(classNameProperty);
                    if ( !(rawClassName instanceof String) ) {
                        throw new IOException("Type name: expected a string in " + classNameProperty + ", but got " + rawClassName);
                    }
                    final String className = (String) rawClassName;
                    final Class<?> concreteClass = classNameToClass.get(className);
                    if ( concreteClass == null ) {
                        throw new IOException("No mapping registered for " + className);
                    }
                    final JsonAdapter<Object> jsonAdapter = jsonAdaptersCache.get(concreteClass);
                    return jsonAdapter.fromJsonValue(jsonObject);
                } catch ( final ExecutionException ex ) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void toJson(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, @Nullable final Object value)
                    throws IOException {
                try {
                    assert value != null;
                    final Class<?> concreteClass = value.getClass();
                    final String className = classToClassName.get(concreteClass);
                    if ( className == null ) {
                        throw new IOException("No mapping registered for " + concreteClass);
                    }
                    final JsonAdapter<Object> valueJsonAdapter = jsonAdaptersCache.get(concreteClass);
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    final Map<String, Object> jsonObject = (Map<String, Object>) valueJsonAdapter.toJsonValue(value);
                    assert jsonObject != null;
                    jsonObject.put(classNameProperty, className);
                    jsonObjectJsonAdapter.toJson(jsonWriter, jsonObject);
                } catch ( final ExecutionException ex ) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

This implementation makes some use of Google Guava for immutable collections (`ImmutableSet`) and caching (`LoadingCache`), but you can easily replace them on your own. I also believe this implementation can be improved for potential Moshi-related performance issues as well.

The trivial example from `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` as seen [here](http://static.javadoc.io/org.danilopianini/gson-extras/0.2.1/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.html) adaptation:

```java
private static final Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder()
        .add(MoshiRuntimeTypeJsonAdapterFactory.of(Shape.class)
                .with(Shape.Circle.class)
                .with(Shape.Diamond.class)
                .with(Shape.Rectangle.class)
        )
        .build();
```

Comment: i usually direct people here: https://github.com/square/moshi/pull/264/files
but there are things i want to improve in it. need to find time...

Comment: @EricCochran Oh, I didn't realize to search in the PRs. Is that PR going to be merged to the master branch?

Comment: I've been meaning to write up a better example than the one I authored above. so, no, not in the state the PR was in.
we may eventually have a published artifact if we get something we like.